# My touchpad stops working when I type

Tags: touchpad

I have a Thinkpad, and I just installed GNOME ubuntu onto it. I want to play minecraft, but whenever I move, I can't move the mouse! I've been looking all over the web for an answer, but I never got one. So can someone please help me?

Comment: Most laptops automatically disable the touchpad while typing - so that you don't accidentally click out of the document or form field you might be typing into. Usually it's something you want, so you don't spend a long time typing then realise you clicked out of the text box and were wasting your time - but in this case not so much. 
If you look in the BIOS settings, is there somewhere to disable this feature?

Comment: There are GNOME extensions that do just that... disable the touchpad when typing. Did you install any extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now in Ubuntu GNOME, but in Ubuntu 14.04 under the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings there is an option for "Disable while typing": 
[image: Mouse & Touchpad]

Since 14.04 uses the same Settings as GNOME, I'd guess this should be similar for your version. Try uncheck the box and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Nope, can't find it.

Comment: It may depend on the touchpad drivers - perhaps Ubuntu doesn't support this option on a Thinkpad. 
Could you check the BIOS settings? I've seen options like this in BIOS before.